# integrating word count topology of storm with kafka

Tags: apache-storm, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

i am trying to integrate word count program of storm with kafka, for that my producer is working fine i.e it is reading a text file and sending each line as a message ,and i could see those messages in simple consumer console.
Now for integrating it with storm i.e to send those messages/lines to consumer spout i have just replaced the previous storm spout of word count program with the kafka spout from storm-spout integration dependency and rest of the program is same and i am trying to run it in eclipse but it is not getting execute ,i dont know what is the problem and even dont know whether i am doing it in right way,here is my main class -

```
package com.spnotes.storm;
import storm.kafka.BrokerHosts;
import storm.kafka.KafkaSpout;
import storm.kafka.SpoutConfig;
import storm.kafka.StringScheme;
import storm.kafka.ZkHosts;
import backtype.storm.Config;
import backtype.storm.LocalCluster;
import backtype.storm.spout.SchemeAsMultiScheme;
import backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;

import com.spnotes.storm.bolts.WordCounterBolt;
import com.spnotes.storm.bolts.WordSpitterBolt;

public class WordCount {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Config config = new Config();
    config.setDebug(true);
    config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING, 1);
    BrokerHosts hosts = new ZkHosts("localhost:9092");
    SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(hosts, "test", "localhost:2181", "id1");
    spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
    KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig);

    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

    builder.setSpout("line-reader-spout", kafkaSpout);

    builder.setBolt("word-spitter", new WordSpitterBolt()).shuffleGrouping("line-reader-spout");

    builder.setBolt("word-counter", new WordCounterBolt()).shuffleGrouping("word-spitter");


    LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
    System.out.println("submit topology");
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    //StormSubmitter.submitTopology("HelloStorm5", config, builder.createTopology());
    cluster.submitTopology("HelloStorm5", config, builder.createTopology());
    cluster.shutdown();
}

}
```

There are 2 bolts WordSplitterBolt() and WordCounterBolt() ,Wordsplitterbolt is breaking each line/message into tokens/words and WordCounterBolt is counting the each word. Can anybody tell me m i doing anything in a wrong way? do i need to create own spout instead of using predefined KafkaSpout ? and is my main class correct?

Comment: BrokerHosts hosts = new ZkHosts(zkConnect);zkConnect is zookeeper hostname and port not for kafka. change it to localhost:2181

Comment: change this to SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(hosts, "test", "", UUID.randomUUID().toString());

Comment: in eclipse its still not running and when i ran it on storm cluster its getting deployed but when i see the logs its giving 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: storm.kafka.KafkaSpout

Comment: and i have already copy pasted the jars - scala-library-2.10.1.jar
kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1.jar and  storm-kafka-0.9.2-incubating.jar to storm lib folder

Comment: add these jars dependency in maven pom.xml.

Comment: its already added now m getting  
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/curator/RetryPolicy
 at storm.kafka.KafkaSpout.open(KafkaSpout.java:85) ~[storm-kafka-0.9.3.jar:0.9.3]

Comment: its zookeeper jar. check zookeeper jar is present in lib

Comment: add this <dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
<artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
<version>0.9.2-incubating</version>
</dependency>

Comment: i have   <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
 <artifactId>storm-kafka</artifactId>
 <version>0.9.3</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: and yes zookeeper-3.4.6.jar is there in storm lib as well as in pom

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73916/discussion-between-gaurav-mishra-and-nsu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change code:

```
        BrokerHosts hosts = new ZkHosts(zkConnect);
```

**zkConnect is zookeeper hostname and port not for kafka. change it to localhost:2181**

As discussed on chat for rest issue related to code.

Issue was with Maven dependency.include all the dependency into POM.xml required.